# Does Gita say bhakti is topmost in any verses?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, bhakti

Does Bhagavad Gita say bhakti is best of all processes anywhere? If yes, does it say it is the only process for realizing god?

Answer (score 2):

In the very last chapter of the Gita, God says(chapter 18, sloka 65):

> Have your mind fixed on Me, **be My devotee**, be a sacrificer to Me and bow down to Me. (Thus) you will come to Me alone. (This) truth do I pormise to you. (For) you are dear to Me.(Translation by Swami Gambhirananda)

So having shown the different paths of Raja-yoga, Jnana-yoga, Karma-yoga and Bhakti-yoga to reach Him, He ultimately asks Arjuna to be His Devoee.

I think He makes Bhakti the top-most by this verse.

At last, Sri Krishna asks Arjuna to leave all dharmas and surrender to Him and assures Him that He will remove all his sins (18/66). This total surrender is in fact the **HIGHEST FORM OF BHAKTI** of the nine forms of it mentioned in Srimadbhagavatam (7.5.23-24) :

(1) śravaṇa ("listening" to the scriptural stories of Krishna and his companions), (2) kīrtana ("praising"; usually refers to ecstatic group singing), (3) smaraṇa ("remembering" or fixing the mind on Vishnu), (4) pāda-sevana(rendering service), (5) arcana (worshiping an image), (6) vandana (paying homage), (7) dāsya (servitude), (8) sākhya (friendship), and (9) ātma-nivedana (complete surrender of the self).

So again we see that God Himself mentions the Topmost form of **Bhakti** as the topmost path for salvation.

Comment: You have the answered the title question .. so even if question is slightly altered urs is still valid as an answer

Comment: If the question is altered to the extent that the given answer is no longer addressing it only then it is unfair .. right now it's ok .. it also gives u the opportunity to answer the newly  added sub-question :D

Comment: No need because partial answers are allowed ..

Comment: Does Gita say it is the only process?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by "topmost"

I think he just says it is easier than attaining the formless God.

https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/12

> Bhagavad Gita 12.1 
>   Arjun inquired: Between those who are steadfastly devoted to Your personal form and those who worship the formless Brahman, who do You consider to be more perfect in Yog?
>
> Bhagavad Gita 12.2 
>   The Blessed Lord said: Those who fix their minds on Me and always engage in My devotion with steadfast faith, I consider them to be the best yogis.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 12.3 – 12.4 
>   But those who worship the formless aspect of the Absolute Truth—the imperishable, the indefinable, the unmanifest, the all-pervading, the unthinkable, the unchanging, the eternal, and the immoveable—by restraining their senses and being even-minded everywhere, such persons, engaged in the welfare of all beings, also attain Me.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 12.5 
>   For those whose minds are attached to the unmanifest, the path of realization is full of tribulations. Worship of the unmanifest is exceedingly difficult for embodied beings.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 12.6 – 12.7 
>   But those who dedicate all their actions to Me, regarding Me as the Supreme goal, worshiping Me and meditating on Me with exclusive devotion, O Parth, I swiftly deliver them from the ocean of birth and death, for their consciousness is united with Me.

Answer (score 2):

Krishna takes Arjuna through karma, jnana and bhakti yogas and gives him a choice in [BG 18.63](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-63/) to as he wishes after telling him whatever he has heard is confidential knowledge. And in [BG 18.64](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-64/), Krishna clearly tells Arjuna he is revealing this confidential knowledge because he considers Arjuna to be a friend.

But, after all that, when it comes to the real solution, he mentions simply [this in BG 18.66](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-66/):

> sarva-dharmān parityajya mām ekaḿ śaraṇaḿ vraja ahaḿ tvāḿ
> sarva-pāpebhyo mokṣayiṣyāmi mā śucaḥ
>
> Commentary by Sri Abhinavagupta of Kaula Tantra Sampradaya:
>
> 18.66 Sarvadharman etc. Abandoning all attributes : This act of slaying the kinsmen and the like that arises incidentally while
> fighting a war – not owning those acts as your own attribute by your
> thought ‘I am the doer of all these’; also giving up by mind, the
> notion ‘If the act of slaying the teacher etc., is avoided, merit will
> accrue to me’. come to Me: Come to Me alone, the Agent-of-all-actions,
> the Supreme Lord, the Sovereign. As your Refuge : as the Guardian of
> all your natural impulses. On that account I, the Omniscient, shall
> rescue you from all the sins. Don’t be sorrowful : Don’t get perplexed
> ‘What to be done’.

It is very clear that he says Arjuna should surrender to him, not just be a devotee or not just as a friend. So, it is clear that sharanagati is either higher than bhakti yoga or it is the end result of bhakti yoga.

Even after saying that he is very clear that [BG 18.71](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-71/) that this message will help only those ***with faith and without Envy***.

Krishna is also clear that surrendering to him, ***as a person, directly***, is the easiest way as mentioned in [BG 12.5](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-12-5/)

> Commentary by Sri Abhinavagupta of Kaula Tantra Sampradaya:
>
> 12.3-5 Ye tu etc. upto avapyate. On the other hand, those, who contemplate on the Self as the motionless Brahman – by them also all
> the attributes of Absolute Lord are superimposed on the Self – the
> attributes that are indicated by the adjectives ‘omni-present’ etc.
> Therefore even the contemplators of the [attributeless] Brahman reach
> nothing but Me, of course. However, the trouble they undergo, is much
> more. For, they [first] superimposed on the Self the actonary of
> attributes like absence-of-sin etc., and then comtemplate on It. Thus,
> while without any effort [on the part of the contemplator] the Lord is
> readily available with the greatness due to the host of
> self-accomplished attributes, these persons undergo two-fold trouble.

Comment: Commentary by Sri Abhinavagupta of Kaula Tantra Sampradaya. It should be Commentary by Sri Abhinavagupta of Trika Sampradaya or Kashmiri Shaivism.

Comment: @Mr.Sigma. I am quoting it asitis on that webpage. So I will just let it be. Thanks for letting me know, though.

Comment: @ikshvaku see? comments are mysteriously disappearing here too.

Comment: @Mr.Sigma. don't worry. its just a joke between us

Answer (score 0):

yes as other users pointed out, bhakti is easier or top. What is that bhakti for? That is explained in 2.47 verse karmanyeva adhikara 2.47. Bhakti is for karma & dharma.

Hope it helps. !!